# Problem with flat mesh, lines may ruin light?

Tags: mesh

I have this problem that i don't the name, but i think it may get me problems with lighting later or but i'm no sure, should find a way to solve it or is nothing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This could be caused by a bevel modifier for example. Upload your object to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) please.

Comment: 1st thing to check: is it definitely flat? if so, the shading artifact might be related to its proximity to the smooth shaded 90 degree angle next to it. Try using an edgesplit modifier or turning on autosmooth.